# Why is subversion not adding certain folders to version control?

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm sharing a subversion repo with the rest of my office. Today I checked out the repo, added a folder (a Drupal installation, if you must know) that has never, ever been version-controlled before, and typed `svn add [foldername]`. This appears to have had the effect of adding all folders, recursing all the way into most of them. After manually adding what didn't get automatically added in the first go, I discovered that two seemingly random folders were not added, but thought that they were, sort of?

```
Ensign-Ro:sites bbinkovitz$ svn add default/
svn: warning: 'default' is already under version control

Ensign-Ro:sites bbinkovitz$ svn add default/*
svn: 'default' is not a working copy
```

This folder does not appear to have, nor ever had, a .svn/ directory in it.

What do I do about this? What causes it?

Comment: I like questions with "emotionally inspired" titles. :)

Comment: Is it possible that someone already added a file with the same name in the Subversion repository, and you just don't have it in your working copy?

Comment: Unlikely. I just checked out the whole repo moments earlier and didn't see a folder with a name that even started with the same letter, let alone had the same filename as the one I am adding.

Comment: It's a long shot, but try `svn cleanup`

Comment: `Ensign-Ro:default bbinkovitz$ svn cleanup`
`svn: '.' is not a working copy directory`

Comment: I could see that happening if you 1) commit it all 2) some process deletes and recreates 'default' 3) you try to commit / add default again

Comment: It would have to have happened in the span of like 30 seconds between my first repo checkout and when I added the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by moving default to default1, adding default1, checking in, then doing `svn mv default1 default` and checking in again.

Answer (score 0):

just try the command without slash,

```
"svn add default"
```